# How to convert json text string into a pandas dataframe from API request?

Tags: python, pandas

trivial question here but how can I convert my api request data into a pandas df

I can only view the data by doing `print(response1.text)`
I'd like it as a dataframe

```
url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"
querystring = {"interval":"1min","function":"TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED","symbol":"GME","datatype":"json","slice":'year1month8'}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "(omitted)"
    }
response1 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd    
url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"
querystring = {"interval":"1min","function":"TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED","symbol":"GME","datatype":"json","slice":'year1month8'}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "(omitted)"
    }
response1 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

response1_json = response1.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(response1_json)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, in return I receive the following error ` Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Hey, from my side looks all good and code is working. May be from your side, you need to check `requests or pandas` lib.

Comment: That's interesting, everything seems fine here too, it may be a deeper issue, I will look into it, thank you!